# Using PEM format certificate in .net core 3.1 on Ubuntu server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel-http-server

everyone
I've read this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21512) and found there is support for PEM format certificate in .net core 3.x. I'm trying to use that but I'm not successful. I can not find any sample code on how to use that. what I have is something like this:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:8678/");//It works now and this is without https
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                      //TODO:

                    
                });
            });
```

In `TODO:` I know we have to have something like this:

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 8678); 
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 8678); 
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 443,
                        listenOptions => { listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password"); });
```

so, what we have to put instead of `"certificate.pfx", "password"` ? I really appreciate any help on that.
The path to my certificate in Ubunto machine is:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/app/fullchain.pem
```

Comment: You say you're not successful, but what does this mean exactly? What error, if any, are you getting. If not an error, what behaviour(s) are you seeing? How do you know you're not successful?

Comment: We do not have test environment and we have to run near-zero downtime. So, I see UseHttps method gets certificate.pfx format with a password, I'm not sure how to use PEM format with this method.

Comment: You should be able to test on your dev box? Have you tried just specifying the PEM and key password?

Comment: yes, you're right. I can install ubuntu with virtual box, store certificate and test locally with kestrel.  but I think there should be some change. because PEM are Base64 encoded ASCII files but PFX format is a binary format, So I thaught maybe I'm wrong with this method. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: pfx is a container for 1 or more public keys & a private key. You can use openssl to combine your certs & private keys into 1 file. It's best to add a password, because some system don't like pfx files without a password, but also because it contains your private keys

Answer (score 2):

PEM support is being added in .NET 5, according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19113).

The way to do it is by adding in `appsettings.json` one of the following configuration:

```
  "Certificates":{
    "Default":{
      "Path": "/some/asp.pem",
      "KeyPath": "/some/asp.key",
      "Password": "password"
    }
  }

  "Certificates":{
    "Default":{
      "Path": "/some/asp.pem",
      "KeyPath": "/some/asp.key",
    }
  }

  "Certificates":{
    "Default":{
      "Path": "/some/asp.crt",
      "KeyPath": "/some/asp.key",
    }
  }
```

Additionally the support for loading certificate chains from configuration is still being developed in this [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/24935) and it might be added in NET5 RC2.
According to mentioned PR you need to specify the `ChainPath` in the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I mentioned, I'm using .net core 3.1, I think it is related to .net framework.

Comment: There is no support for PEM certificates in .Net Core 3.x. You either upgrade to .NET5 or keep using .Net Core 3.1 but with PFX certificates.

Comment: but they announced they have this support, based on this link:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21512

Comment: As I said, the support is being added in .Net 5, you can also see what tags has the issue you linked: `davidfowl added this to the 5.0.0 milestone on May 5`